# Pass argument from shell script to Python script without having to specify argument on command line

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want to execute a shell script without having to specify any additional  arguments on the command line itself. Instead I would like to hard code the arguments, e.g. input file name and file path, in the shell script.

Toy shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

time python3 path/to/pyscript/graph.py \
  --input-file-path=path/to/file/myfile.tsv
```

So, when I run `$ ./script.sh`, the script should pass the input file information to the py script.

Can this be done? I invariably get the error "no such directory or file" ...

Note, I will deal with the arguments on the python script side using `argparse`.

**EDIT**

It turns out that the issue was caused by something I had omitted from my toy script above because I didn't think that it could be the cause. In fact I had a line commented out and it was this line which prevented the script from running.

Toy shell script Full Version:

```
#!/bin/bash

time python3 path/to/pyscript/graph.py \
# this commented out line prevents the script from running
  --input-file-path=path/to/file/myfile.tsv
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run python script from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your script is correct but the file path is wrong. Maybe you forgot a leading forward slash.  Anyway, make sure that `path/to/pyscript/graph.py` and `path/to/file/myfile.tsv` are correct.

A dummy example of how to call a python script with hard-coded arguments from a BASH script:

```
$ cat dummy_script.py 
import argparse
import os
import time

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input-file-path")
args = parser.parse_args()

if os.path.isfile(args.input_file_path):
    print args.input_file_path, "is a file"
    print "sleeping a second"
    time.sleep(1)

$ cat time_python_script.sh
time python dummy_script.py --input-file-path=/etc/passwd

$ /bin/bash time_python_script.sh
/etc/passwd is a file
sleeping a second

real    0m1.047s
user    0m0.028s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Comment: In line `--input-file-path=/etc/passwd`
`=` is not required.
It should be `--input-file-path /etc/passwd`

Comment: @MichaelD, wouldn't that simply mean that the characters " " and "=" are equivalent in this context? Are there any benefits to using " " rather than "=" as a delimiter?